# How can the normal force do work when pushing on a book?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

In the answer to question 5.1 of "Problems and Solutions in Introductory Mechanics" by David Morin, he says that:

> A normal force does work if you push on a book with your hand

I'm unable to imagine what he means by this. If we are talking about pushing the book sideways, the normal force is perpendicular to the motion and doesn't do work.

If we are talking about pushing from the top of the book sitting on a surface, then there's no motion.

Could anyone clarify how his answer makes sense?

Comment: So, how did he defend the statement. Let's see this in context.

Comment: He doesn't justify the statement further. The question was about what forces can do work and one of the options is the normal force. His answer only says what I quoted

Comment: Yes, but you originally said he "defends", then you edited as he "says". My comment was on your original statement.

Comment: Yes. I edited it to avoid further confusion. As "defends" may imply there's a further justification I'm skipping

Comment: If you consider the book and table as rigid bodies, then no work is done as there is no displacement of the book. But if you consider the book and table as deformable bodies, which all real bodies are, then work is done as the book and table compress.

Comment: He might be referring to the normal force exerted by the hand, rather than that from the table.

Comment: I'm starting to realize in my many years of teaching and tutoring that the term "normal force" causes more harm than help.

Comment: Thanks, @Steeven. I went back to another chapter and Morin defines what he means by normal force. "[...] the leftward force from your hand is itself a normal force pushing on the block", with this definition in mind his answer makes sense now. I was thinking of the usually defined normal force from a book sitting on a surface

Answer (score 2):

"Normal" is a synonym for "perpendicular".  The applied force is perpendicular to the book.  The table provides a different normal force.

We are accustomed to think of a normal force as being able to provide whatever force is necessary to maintain equilibrium on a system such as a book and a table. The mechanism is elastic deformation of the table.  Note that the proximal agent of that normal force is the last layer of molecules on the table's surface.

The same reasoning can be applied to the applied force.  Whatever force is necessary to maintain equilibrium (or acceleration) is provided by deformation of the agent, the proximal agent being the last layer of molecules.

Technically correct, I suppose, but confusing without context because it is not standard terminology.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was also thinking if it could be argued that if I push a book horizontally, the book is exerting a normal force on my hand and as my hand is moving, the normal force is doing negative work in this case?

Comment: We have a third-law pair action-reaction pair, the agent (finger, pencil, whatever) on the book, and the book on the agent.  The former does positive work on the latter, and the latter does negative work on the agent.